# selenium webdriver: InternetExplorerDriver server is not started

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

i use selenium web driver with junit in Eclipse. This is begining of my test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class WebTest {
private WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void testUnit() throws Exception {

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

After running test I get the message:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.24.2.0
Listening on port 39133
Jul 03, 2012 3:46:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Jul 03, 2012 3:46:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

I attach IEDriverServer, set it to this directory `E:\eclipse\WebDriver` and add to path.

Why does this message appear and how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEDriverServer.exe uses an HTTP server for the language bindings to communicate with. When the language bindings launch the server, this HTTP server takes a little time to initialize and be ready to receive communications from the language binding. The language binding polls until it receives a valid response from the HTTP server component of the IEDriverServer.exe. The message you are seeing indicates that the server hasn't finished initializing yet, and is simply informational; it can be safely ignored.